# delayed socket communication when sending mail with java

Tags: java, windows, sockets, email, localhost

When sending a test email on my Windows 7 system there is a **very long delay** of 20 seconds in total. I already tried different smtp server implementations (jsmtpd, subethasmtp) but both show the same delay. Running the same test on a linux system has no delay. Is this a windows localhost networking issue?

My sample code:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
import org.subethamail.wiser.Wiser;

public class C_MailerTest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.setProperty( DefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_LEVEL, Level.DEBUG.name() );
        Wiser wiser = new Wiser();
        wiser.start();

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            @Override
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                mimeMessage.setRecipient( Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress( "mail@yourcompany.com" ) );
                mimeMessage.setFrom( new InternetAddress( "mail@mycompany.com" ) );
                mimeMessage.setText( "test" );
            }
        };

        JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        sender.setHost( "127.0.0.1" );
        System.out.println( "sending mail" );
        sender.send(preparator);

        System.out.println( "mails received: " + wiser.getMessages().size() );
        wiser.stop();
    }
}
```

And here are the logs (windows 7 enterprise, service pack 1):

```
09:36:04.340 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: AUTH
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: DATA
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: EHLO
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: HELO
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: HELP
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: MAIL
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: NOOP
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: QUIT
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: RCPT
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: RSET
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: STARTTLS
09:36:04.341 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: VRFY
sending mail
09:36:04.444 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - SMTP connection count: 1
09:36:04.451 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 220 SWE-JPW.intern.src ESMTP SubEthaSMTP
09:36:04.455 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: EHLO SWE-JPW.intern.src
09:36:04.461 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250-SWE-JPW.intern.src
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
09:36:04.481 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: MAIL FROM:<mail@mycompany.com>
09:36:04.481 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:36:04.484 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: RCPT TO:<mail@yourcompany.com>
09:36:04.484 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:36:09.495 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: NOOP
09:36:09.495 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:36:14.495 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: NOOP
09:36:14.495 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:36:19.495 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: NOOP
09:36:19.495 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:36:24.049 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: DATA
09:36:24.049 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
09:36:24.051 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:36:24.055 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: QUIT
09:36:24.055 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 221 Bye
mails received: 1
09:36:24.058 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer] INFO  org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer - SMTP Server socket shut down.
```

There are a lot of NOOP log entries delayed excactly 5 seconds.

The logs running the same test on a linux machine (ubuntu):

```
09:53:55.312 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: AUTH
09:53:55.313 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: DATA
09:53:55.313 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: EHLO
09:53:55.313 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: HELO
09:53:55.313 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: HELP
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: MAIL
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: NOOP
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: QUIT
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: RCPT
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: RSET
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: STARTTLS
09:53:55.314 [main] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler - Added command: VRFY
sending mail
09:53:55.395 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - SMTP connection count: 1
09:53:55.397 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 220 vm-gkls ESMTP SubEthaSMTP
09:53:55.399 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: EHLO vm-gkls
09:53:55.402 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250-vm-gkls
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
09:53:55.422 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: MAIL FROM:<mail@mycompany.com>
09:53:55.422 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:53:55.423 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: RCPT TO:<mail@yourcompany.com>
09:53:55.423 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:53:55.423 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: DATA
09:53:55.423 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
09:53:55.426 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 250 Ok
09:53:55.427 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Client: QUIT
09:53:55.427 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler] DEBUG org.subethamail.smtp.server.ConnectionHandler - Server: 221 Bye
mails received: 1
09:53:55.429 [org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer] INFO  org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer - SMTP Server socket shut down.
```

On a linux system there is absolutely no delay. The program sends and receives the mail immediately.

Environment:

- java 8 (1.8.0-91)
- spring 4.2.6
- javax.mail 1.5.5
- subethasmtp-wiser 1.2

Comment: It seems that this is a windows problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2861819

Comment: ... and that the hotfix is not applicable to my system :-(

Comment: Switching to Windows Server 2012 resolved the problem.